# How to Reset Material RangeSlider values Programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am using **com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider** in my project in filter screen, I want to reset range from and range to sliding progress programmatically when the user clears the filter.

```
 <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
                                android:id="@+id/avg_due_days_spinner"
                                style="@style/SliderStyleBlue"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/text_description_blue_average_due_days_range_filter"
                                android:valueFrom="0"
                                android:valueTo="999"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                tools:visibility="visible"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvText_averageDueDays_DialogFilterReceivables"
                                app:thumbColor="@color/color_blue"
                                app:thumbRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                app:trackColorActive="@color/color_blue"
                                app:trackColorInactive="@color/color_inactive_bar"
                                app:values="@array/range_slider_values_average_due" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the current max and min value in a variable
2. When the user clears the filter get the value from the stored variable and
   set the values using

   rangeslider.setValues(minValue, maxValue)

Comment: mBinding.avgDueDaysSpinner.setValues((float) 0, 999F); ---- Already tried this but not work for me.